# Javascript ES6 - How to add dynamic property to an object?

Tags: javascript

How can I add a dynamic property with multiple attributes?
I tried with backticks, but it did not work.

```
function User(userID){
   this.userID = userID;
   this.printUserDetails = function(){
       console.log(userID);
   }
}

const user=new User('A1234');

user.tokenID='jsessionID=12345678';

user.tokenValidity={
    startDate:07042020
    //What is the syntax to add end date here for e.g. endDate:08042020?
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do something like `user.tokenValidity.endDate = 08042020`? Or what do you mean by dynamic property. I see `user` is of type `User`. Do you want to add `endDate` to the constructor function `User`, or just to `user`? If the second option is true, you should be able to add it as I mentioned. If not, please provide more details as what is the error you get and what do you do to get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working:

```js
function User(userID){
   this.userID = userID;
   this.printUserDetails = function(){
       console.log(userID);
   }
}

const user=new User('A1234');

user.tokenID='jsessionID=12345678';

user.tokenValidity={
    startDate:07042020,
    endDate:5464644
}
console.log(user)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.assign`

```js
function User(userID) {
  this.userID = userID;
  this.printUserDetails = function() {
    console.log(userID);
  }
}
const user = new User('A1234');

Object.assign(user, {
  tokenID: 'jsessionID=12345678',
  tokenValidity: {
    startDate: 07042020,
    endDate: 08042020
  }
})

console.log(user);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

I would actually make this a class, if you are using ES6.

```js
class User {
  constructor(userId, properties={}) {
    this.userId = userId
    this.properties = properties
  }
  assignProperty(key, value) {
    Object.assign(this.properties, { [key] : value })
  }
  assignProperties(properties) {
    Object.assign(this.properties, properties)
  }
  printUserDetails() {
    console.log({
      userId : this.userId,
      properties : this.properties
    })
  }
}

const user = new User('A1234')

user.assignProperties({
  tokenId: 'jsessionID=12345678',
  tokenValidity: {
    startDate: 07042020,
    endDate: 08042020
  }
})

user.printUserDetails()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```